# Trying to use API key with curl to access Cloudant

Tags: authentication, curl, cloudant

I want to use `curl` to access Cloudant without my user and password.  I've created an API key for a database, have a key & password combination, and have granted admin, read, and write permission to the API key.  Now what?  Where do I specify the key and/or password?

I tried:

```
curl -u key https://user.cloudant.com/_all_dbs
```

It asks for the password for which I supply the password associated with the key and I get:

```
{"error":"forbidden","reason":"one of _all_dbs, _admin, server_admin is required for this request"}
```

I can form a command using my real user and password but I want to avoid that!

Comment: I was able to form a command to get all the documents of a specific database using the key and password combination.  So maybe I just can't do `_all_dbs`.  After all, the API key was not authorized for all the databases.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is between [Authentication](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/authentication.html#authentication) and [Authorization](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/authorization.html#creating-api-keys). You need to authenticate with a username and password to admin the database or use the web dashboard — or do things like get `_all_dbs`. API keys only work to give access to specific databases with specific permissions. So even if you give the API key access to all the databases, your call to `_all_dbs_` still shouldn't work. Hope that helps.